# Should "Did Jesus really use wine at the Last Supper?" really have been closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

[**Did Jesus really use wine at the Last Supper?**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/80147/did-jesus-really-use-wine-at-the-last-supper)

The above question has been closed as a duplicate of the following questions:

- [**What are the Church Laws governing ingredients and shapes of altar bread in the Catholic Church?**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71046/what-are-the-church-laws-governing-ingredients-and-shapes-of-altar-bread-in-the)
- [**When the Bible talks about wine does it mean alcoholic wine?**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24/when-the-bible-talks-about-wine-does-it-mean-alcoholic-wine)

Do not know if it is only myself that thinks this question has enough merit, even if poorly constructed, to stand on its own as not being a duplicate at all.

The questioner seeks a Catholic response and thus just not a generic answer!

Is this this just me or do others see this a not a duplicate?

Any input on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NigelJ I must disagree with you on both counts. The accepted answer does not meet the question’s parameters and the OP had asked for a Catholic response from the beginning.

Comment: I have checked the edit history and you are correct. The first original did, in fact, point towards a Catholic answer. My memory was faulty on that. I shall leave the other matter (of a satisfactory answer) and not comment again upon it.

Comment: Agree it's not a duplicate of those questions. It could be a duplicate of something else... I didn't check.